# What happened to Salvage?

Tags: destiny

Salvage disappeared early on despite the fact Trophies/Achievements were still available, what happened to the Salvage gametype?

Comment: I don't believe this is off-topic. As @LasseV.Karlsen has shown, this knowledge is not restricted to developer only knowledge.

Comment: @Ben The fact that there is information available is beside the point; it requires information that came from the developer in order to answer.  Take a look at the beginning of the article: "Bungie has announced".  We don't allow questions that ask for developer intent.  That's exactly what this question is.

Comment: @Frank could it be improved by asking if it is now an event, rather than _why_ it was removed?

Comment: Well, you're now trying to shoehorn it into an acceptable question, using the answer to do it.  I believe it may be acceptable if you focus more on the fact that Salvage was removed, but there are still achievements active for it.  If you take out the first sentence asking for why it was removed, that itself would make it a much more acceptable question.  "Less why, more what" tends to make questions better here, especially when it requires knowledge outside of a game to answer.

Comment: @Frank Ahh on TGO sometimes the answers help mould the questions when they risk closure, didn't realise that's unacceptable here - I'll remove the first part of the sentence. - please see my amend.

Comment: It's especially strange that the bounties for it still show up when it's not active. Lots of confusion generated by it being an occasional event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Salvage is currently on a vacation while the Queens Emissary and friends are in town.

Salvage will return later this month after the Queen has departed.

There will apparently be some kind of rotation in place so that every week/month there may be some modes coming, and some going.

[Source: Metro](http://metro.co.uk/2014/09/19/combined-arms-starts-today-on-destiny-the-queens-wrath-next-week-4874643/).